# Background image css code causing broken links?

Tags: html, css

EDIT: The #backgroundimage was the issue. I removed that, and the links work! Thank you so much for the suggestion/answer!

I'm working on a basic site with a background image, and some links/images. I seem to have a bug in my background image css code because when I remove it, the links suddenly work. I've tried playing around with the css, but it either removes the links, or the background image. I've searched the site but can't find an answer?

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/stylec.css">
        <title>About Joshua Taylor</title>
    </head>

    <div id="backgroundimage"></div>
    <h2>Welcome to my page</h2>
    <body>
        <nav>   
            <ul class="nav">     
                <li>       
                    <a href="index.html">About Me</a>     
                </li>     
                <li>       
                    <a href="../htmlfirstpage/newsexample.html">Recommended Articles
                    </a>     
                </li>   
                <li>       
                    <a href="../htmlfirstpage/mywork.html">My Work</a>     
                </li>  
                <li>       
                    <a href="../htmlfirstpage/contact.html">Contact</a>     
                </li>  
            </ul> 
        </nav>      
        </body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
html 
{ 
  background: url(../images/urban.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
 }
#backgroundimage {
  position: fixed; 
  top: -50%; 
  left: -50%; 
  width: 200%; 
  height: 200%;
}
#backgroundimage img {
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0; 
  bottom: 0; 
  margin: auto; 
  min-width: 50%;
  min-height: 50%;
  }

h2
{
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

ul.nav
{   
  list-style: none;   padding: 4px; 
  color: white;
} 

ul.nav li
{   
  display: inline; 
  color: white;
}

a:link { 
  color: white; 
} 
a:visited { 
  color: white; 
} 
a:hover { 
  color: white; 
  text-decoration: underline;
} 
a:active { 
  color: white; 
}

img {
  width: 42px; 
  height: 42px;
}
```

Comment: How can a background image cause broken links. There may be other errors

Comment: Post your html too, and it's better to provide a fiddle to see what exactly is happening

Comment: I'm at a loss for how the background image would break your links.  Maybe add a higher z-index to your links?

Comment: The posted HTML is invalid you have elements outside of the `<body>`. Yeah...looks like z-index issue because of that.

Comment: my bad but i dont understand why write #backgroundimage img if there's no image in that particular div ?